# consul-template using Address not ServiceAddress in template

Tags: bash, nginx, docker, consul, consul-template

I am having a problem in that consul-template seems to be substituting the service "ServiceAddress" and not "Address" in my template and I wonder if anyone can tell me why.

From a bash session within my nginx container where consul-template is also running I can fetch the service definition from Consul with:

```
curl http://consul-server.service.consul:8500/v1/catalog/service/service1
[{"Node":"ip-172-31-24-202","Address":"172.31.24.202","ServiceID":"ip-172-31-24-202:service1:23141","ServiceName":"service1","ServiceTags":null,"ServiceAddress":"172.17.0.3","ServicePort":32809}]
```

My consul-template template file looks like:

```
{{range service "service1"}}server {{.Address}}:{{.Port}};
```

I would expect this to output the `Address`, and not the `ServiceAddress` for the service. However, the below happens:

```
consul-template -consul consul-server.service.consul:8500 -template "/var/templates/service1.conf.tmpl" -dry -once

server 172.17.0.3:32809
```

Comment: Yes it is so confusing that we are not exposed the service catalog when iterating w/ `{{ range service "myservice" }}`. Thanks for pointing that out and hinting towards Registrator's `-ip` flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured this out, `.Address` is part of the Consul response metadata, and not really part of the service metadata. This confused me because my consul Client is running on the same host.

I changed the `-ip` argument to the Registrator service I was running to be the internal IP address of the host running docker (rather than the default which is the IP of the Docker container) and everything worked.